# Any difference between these three sentences?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, word-choice

- 彼は私達に騒がないように頼んだ。
- 彼は私達に騒がないと頼んだ。
- 彼は私達に騒がない頼んだ。

Is there any difference between those?

Comment: Only the first one is correct. You may want to rephrase your question.

Comment: @user27280 Even if it doesn't make sense, is the grammar okay in the second example? For example, would this be correct: 彼は私達に騒ぐなと頼んだ

Comment: @user27280 yeah I'd like to know why it's incorrect because they all look correct to me

Comment: @user3856370 「騒ぐな」would be more than a request, it would be a tongue-lashing (舌打ち）or an order (命令）, so 頼む wouldn't be an appropriate verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 彼は私たちに騒がないように頼んだ。◎　He told us not to be noisy.

No issues with this sentence.

> 彼は私たちに騒がないと頼んだ。✘

Without the ように, we would assume that the と is functioning as a quotative particle, which means that 「騒がない」would be what is being quoted. 「騒がないで」would be an appropriate fix.

```
彼は私たちに「騒がないで」と頼んだ。◎ He told us 'Don't be noisy'.
```

> 彼は私たちに騒がない頼んだ。✘

Using the simple negative form 「ない」 here would serve an adjectival function.  Therefore, the verb should be changed to a noun (頼み）.

```
私たちは彼に騒がないという頼みを受けたんだ。【～微妙～】　
'We received a request from him to not be noisy.
```

Probably best to avoid this last one as, despite being better grammatically, it is an unusual way to form the expression.

Comment: 「私たちは彼に騒がないという頼みを受けたんだ。」might be understandable but sounds unnatural. 「私たちは彼に騒がない頼みを受けたんだ。」 sounds unnatural and probably incorrect. We'd normally say 「私たちは彼に騒がないで｛くれと/ほしいと｝頼まれた」 (or maaybe 「私たちは彼｛に/から｝～～ないで｛くれと/ほしいと｝いう依頼を受けた」 as far as grammar goes)

Comment: @Chocolate  いつも、賢明な助言ありがとうございます：）